# How to make OpenVPN Connect work in a multi-user macos?

Tags: user-account, vpn, startup, fast-user-switching

How to make OpenVPN Connect work in a multi-user setup in macos 14?

If it launches after a user logs in and OpenVPN Connect launches there, then after the user logs out and another one logs in, the second user cannot use OpenVPN Connect because it doesn't even start. Only restart helps.